# Create nested JSON in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk",
  "title": "Design Milk",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "user/category/test",
      "label": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm doing it with this method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *req = [NSMutableDictionary @"feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk" forKey:@"id"];
[req @"Design Milk" forKey:@"title"];

NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"user/category/test", @"id", @"test", @"label",
                     nil];

[req setObject:tmp forKey:@"categories"];

NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:req options:0 error:&error];
```

However, this isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then you will realize that you're missing a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code isn't going to compile, so you need to fix that.

The value of "categories" in your example output is an array with one element, which happens to be a dictionary. So you need

```
NSDictionary* oneCategory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...];
NSArray* categories = [NSArray arrayWithObject:oneCategory];
[req setObject:categories forKey:@"categories"];
```

And you should really use more modern syntax, like

```
req [@"categories"] = @[oneCategory];
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing an array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *req =[NSMutableDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk", @"id", nil];
req[@"title"] = @"Design Milk";
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"user/category/test", @"id",
                     @"test", @"label",
                     nil];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:tmp];
[req setObject:arr forKey:@"categories"];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:req options:0 error:&error];
```